# How to delay the conversion of the result of an async method?

Tags: c#, async-await

Lets suppose I'm wrapping a complex API, and I have my own result types that I want to return out of async methods that wrap underlying async methods.

```
interface IMyWrapper
{
    Task<MyResult> GetResultAsync(string arg);
}
```

the obvious way to do this is to await the result of the underlying call, convert the result and pass it back

```
class MyWrapper: IMyWrapper
{
    private IUnderlyingObject theirObject;
    public async Task<MyResult> GetResultAsync(string arg)
    {
        var theirResult = await theirObject.GetResultAsync(arg);
        return new MyResult(theirResult);
    }
}
```

Lets say I have client code using `MyWrapper` on the lines of . . .

```
var wrapper = new MyWrapper();

var taskA = wrapper.GetResultAsync("A"); // Call A
var taskB = wrapper.GetResultAsync("B"); // Call B

var apiTask = someApi.DoTheThingAsync(); // Call C

var api = await apiTask;
var a = await taskA;
var b = await taskB;

DoSomethingElse(api, a, b); . . .
```

I assume that the `Call A` completes before `Call B` starts and it completes before `Call C` starts. This negates the whole point of async code.

Is my assumption accurate, or am I missing something, and if I am missing something what is it?

If I'm not missing something, how do I delay, or taskify (I'm sure it's a word) the conversion of their result to my result type?

*Practical considerations*

The real method sometimes calls the underlying api, and sometimes does something else. 
The object returned by the underlying api is a concrete type with no public constructor, so I can't create one and return it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I assume that the Call A completes before Call B starts and it completes before Call C starts.

That assumption is incorrect.  Call A *can* complete before Call B starts, if it completes *really* fast, but there's nothing forcing it to, so it almost certainly won't.

> Is my assumption accurate, or am I missing something, and if I am missing something what is it?

You seem to be missing that when you call an async method it won't necessarily be completed when it returns.  The whole *point* of an `async` method is that it returns before the actual work has been completed and that the work is completed at some point in the future.  Calling several async methods in a row won't force the first to be complete before the next starts; that would only be true of synchronous code.

Comment: I actually proved this to myself when I started playing with async and await a couple of months ago, but managed to confused the hell out of my self now that I've started using it. Thanks Servy.

Answer (score 2):

No, your assumption is wrong. Task B(even Task C) can start before Task A is completed and they can get completed in any order. The only you can assure is "DoSomethingElse" will be called once all tasks are completed.

Answer (score 0):

In the code above, the first thing to be completed is the Call C, then the Call A and finally the Call B.

```
var api = await apiTask; // Call C
var a = await taskA; // Call A
var b = await taskB; // Call B
```

Comment: But `wrapper.GetResultAsync` has an _await_, that doesn't **stop** the other methods from being called?

Answer (score -1):

In order to await all the tasks you need to use **TaskWhenAll**

```
await Task.WhenAll(apiTask,taskA,taskB);

//All tasks have been completed and it's safe to access the result.
DoSomethingEsle(apiTask.Result, taskA.Result, taskB.Result);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this really doesn't answer anything in the question.

Comment: No, you *don't* need to use `WhenAll`.  Just awaiting all of the tasks, as he does, is perfectly fine.

Comment: Call A is going to run up to the point where it let's go of the current thread.  For example if theirObject.GetResultAsync makes a Web API call to the server, the thread is free to start processing Call B.  At this point which ever completes first, it'll pick up creating your MyResult.  It may be Call A, but it's also possible for it to be the Call B.  By using Task.WhenAll, you are waiting for all 3 tasks to complete before accessing the results.

Comment: @M.Tovbin: If you'd put that comment in the answer I would have upvoted it (I didn't downvote btw).

Comment: @M.Tovbin It's no different using `WhenAll` than just awaiting all 3 in turn after starting all 3, as he does in his original code.

Comment: @Servy I can agree with that... I should've read the question closer. If it was var result = await wrapper.GetResultAsync("A"); etc... then it would run 1 GetResult at a time.  In this case he was assigning to the tasks and awaiting the tasks.